# while running netron on colab, getting this "OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use" error

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

I'm using [Netron](https://github.com/lutzroeder/netron), for visualizing the model on Colab. as shown in this [notebook](https://github.com/microsoft/onnxruntime/blob/master/onnxruntime/python/tools/transformers/notebooks/PyTorch_Bert-Squad_OnnxRuntime_CPU.ipynb) line 11.
when I run the following script to view the model,

```
import netron

enable_netron = True
if enable_netron:
    netron.start(optimized_model_path)
```

am getting this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-86b0c5c2423c> in <module>()
      5 if enable_netron:
----> 6     netron.start(optimized_model_path)

5 frames
/usr/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py in server_bind(self)
    468         if self.allow_reuse_address:
    469             self.socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
--> 470         self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
    471         self.server_address = self.socket.getsockname()
    472 

OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use
```

how can I fix this issue?

Ik I can use its desktop version of the app and give it the model but how can use Netron in colab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be able to use `portpicker.pick_unused_port()`.

Here's a simple example:
https://colab.research.google.com/gist/blois/227d21df87fe8a390c2a23a93b3726f0/netron.ipynb

Comment: the netron in the above notebook works fine, the model size in the notebook is 10MB & its type is `.tflite`. but my models are of `.onnx`  and `.pt ` type and both of their sizes are  418MB.

Comment: while running my model I'm getting `github.com refused to connect.` error for the onnx model and for .pt it just opens the netorn as in its [netorn.app](https://netron.app/) site with model selection option. how do I resolve this? thank you! @blois